# Animation from large number of jpg files

Tags: animation, imagemagick, jpeg

I have more than 100,000 jpg images in a directory and want to create an animation from these files. These files are sequentially numbered from file1 to file125000. I have tried using ImageMagick and many other free tools, but hasn't worked. After 3 hours, imagemagick gave an error saying that the number of files is too large. Is there any tool (Windows) that can process this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg with a command like this one:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -r 30 -i image%06d.jpg -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 video.mp4
```

ffmpeg command line have a structure like this:

```
ffmpeg [input params] -i <input> [output params] <output>
```

Input params are:

- **-f**: is used to force input or output format. In my example is used to indicate that input file is intended to be parsed as **image2**, an internal ffmpeg format which can be used to specify multiple images using a pattern;
- **-r**: can be used to force frame rate both on input or output. If used only on input, output framerate is inherited.
- **-i image%06d.jpg**: this flag specify to read all image with 6 integer digits, filled with leading zeroes (from **image000000.jpg** to **image999999.jpg**). Of course ffmpeg will stop at last existing file.

Other params are used to specify output format and video codec. In particular:

- **-codec:v libx264**: specify video codec (x264 using libx264)
- **-crf 23**: this parameter is peculiar of x264 encoder, used to specify Constant RateFactor, and influences output bitrate and others.
- **video.mp4**: If not specified, FFMpeg try to guess output format from the output file name. In my example I used **.mp4**, so FFmpeg will encode video using libx264 encoder and MP4 format.

FFMpeg windows build can be download from zeranoe

Edit: if your images names don't have leading zeroes try using file%6d.jpg instead of file%06d.jpg as input filename (without 0).

Comment: Rather than giving a man a single fish for supper, could you maybe teach us how to catch fish so we can do it ourselves please ;-) I can see `-r 30` is probably a frame rate of 30 fps, and that `-i image%06d` might select a bunch of input images, but what about `-f image2` and `-crf 23`?

Comment: I preferred to keep to answer simple. Explaining ffmpeg may be out of topic... But I'm editing my answer adding useful informations.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.